# Приложение Android Studio не запускается с иконки на телефоне

Tags: android, android-intent

Мое приложение запускается через Android Studio на телефоне по USB:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но когда я пытаюсь запустить его через иконку приложения на экране телефона, то оно мгновенно вылетает

В Logcat пишет эту ошибку:
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.tweetapp/com.example.tweetapp.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.example.tweetapp.Post.getAuthor()' on a null object reference

Он пытается выполнить этот метод:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Однако этот метод должен вызываться только когда элемент arguments типа Bundle содержит какие-то данные переданные из другого activity
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я вывел в Log содержание элемента arguments и вот что написало:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Однако arguments должен быть пустой. Если я запускаю на телефоне приложение через ПК, то оно работает как надо, однако почему-то при запуске с иконки на телефоне оно не работает, да еще и arguments содержит какие-то данные. Помогите решить проблему пж.

Comment: Да, немного странно. Можно поразбираться почему так, а можно просто проверять наличие самих данных, а не их контейнера.

Comment: а как вы их туда помещаете?..

Comment: Выведите в лог все ключи, будет понятнее что там вам приходит и откуда. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/BaseBundle#keySet()